# Executing a python script REMOTELY, using another python script

Tags: python, execution

I have a python script in a remote system.
I need to run the script stored in remote system from my system, and I need a python script to do so.
Both the systems are windows.

I have found many answers when I searched, but none of them was a python script.

Please help me. If possible, a python code showing an example will be extremely helpful.

Comment: You probably want Fabric. But recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Why python script in particular? Bash is allowed in Windows. Why not use bash?

Comment: Did u check https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html subprocess/os.system calls? This is also an excellent one - https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/. I am not sure if it covers your expectations.

Comment: yogi linked to an old version of the Pyro4 documentation, the new location is here https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Thank you, I went through the pyro documentation. I have to write a server side script and a client side script for communicating with each other. That is fine, I can do. But the problem is that I need to invoke the client side script using my local system. That is the problem I am facing.